# Making photo from browser

Tags: plugins, photo

I have a camera Canon 550 D and i need to integrate camera with browser.
How to make a photo from browser? May be some plugins?
Process should look like this: 
Client clicks "Photograph" and browser sends signal to camera which takes shot and responds with image.

Comment: Normally this is the sort of thing that requires you to use Flash (as in Adobe). The camera will still need to be connected to the computer, though, and at that rate, though, what advantage do you gain in jumping through all the hoops of going through a browser?

Comment: Camera is connected to computer. That's ok. I am developing web app where operator need to take a photo of client for ID card. There is also a device for capturing "sign". For security reasons operator cannot save as image and upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My company outsourced this task and solution is to use applet which uses dll for connection to camera